# S4 won't see connection to PC at either end

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-s-4, connection-issues, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging

Have a Verizon 4.4.3 Galaxy S4 using the standard cable. When I connect to the PC, the PC doesn't show it in explorer. The phone doesn't bring up the connection notification. I have enabled/disabled developer options. Re-installed the drivers. Tried different USB ports. In the end all it does is charge. I know this worked before as I have done it before, but this was before many updates ago.

The reason I need this is for debugging an android application I am developing.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with different cables?

Comment: I do not have any other cables

Comment: Buy a different cable

Answer (score 0):

Samsung usb cables have a history of being finicky with data connections. I know it personally from trying to root several Galaxy phones over the years. Your best bet is to buy another usb cable. I highly recommend cables from Monoprice as they are cheap and high quality. However to be fair, any good quality cable you can find from another manufacture would be your best bet.